# 'Cannot read property 'set' of undefined' Error For 'this.$cookies.set'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vue-cookies

I'm trying to set up some rudimentary cookies for my Vue project and I'm running into the title error when trying to set a cookie. I'm using vue-cookies version ^1.7.4 according to my package.json file. The full error message is as follows when I click my button to make a cookie:

```html
ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Proxy.setCookie (VM6493 Register.vue:45)
    at Object.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (Register.vue?db27:29)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:333)
setCookie @ VM6493 Register.vue:45
Object.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> @ Register.vue?db27:29
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:333
```

The page with the cookie-setting button is this Register.vue file:

```html
<template>
  <layout>
    <button v-on:click="setCookie()">Click For Cookie</button>
  </layout>
</template>

<script>
import Layout from "./components/Layout";
import axios from "axios";


export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    Layout,
    vlink
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      username: "",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setCookie() {
      this.$cookies.set("username", "bilbobaggins")
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I get this warning when navigating to the Register.vue page:

```html
[Vue warn]: Extraneous non-props attributes (install, config, get, set, remove, isKey, keys) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. 
  at <Layout install=fn<install> config=fn<config> get=fn<get>  ... > 
  at <Home install=fn<install> config=fn<config> get=fn<get>  ... > 
  at <App install=fn<install> config=fn<config> get=fn<get>  ... >
```

Here's my main.js file:

```html
import {createApp, h} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Register from "./Register"
import "./vue-api-call/styles.css"
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'


const routes = {'/': App, '/register': Register}
const SimpleRouter = {
  data: () => ({
    currentRoute: window.location.pathname
  }),
  computed: {
    CurrentComponent() {
      return routes[this.currentRoute]
    }
  },
  render() {
    return h(this.CurrentComponent)
  }
}


createApp(SimpleRouter, VueCookies).mount("#app")
```

I have tried changing my function in the Register.vue file from 'this' to 'window' or 'VueCookies' after importing it but, that did not work. I also tried different methods to '.use' the VueCookies module in my main.js file but, I'm either not good at that or it's not the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: Just tried importing Vue-Cookies in the script section of my Register.vue file and changing the function to `VueCookies.VueCookies.set("username", "bilbobaggins")` but, that gives the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `vue-cookie` module doesn't work with Vue 3, because the `install` function uses the Vue 2 version `Vue.prototype.$cookie` to make it available in all components. `Vue.prototype` is now `Vue.config.globalProperties` in Vue 3 (https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#vue-prototype-replaced-by-config-globalproperties). That's still an open issue in the `vue-cookie` module GitHub repo: https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies/issues/59.

If you're using Vue 3, then you need to go to the `vue-cookies` node module and change this:

```js
install: function (Vue) {
            Vue.prototype.$cookie = this;
            Vue.cookie = this;
        },
```

to this:

```js
install: function (Vue) {
            Vue.prototype ? Vue.prototype.$cookies = this : Vue.config.globalProperties.$cookies = this;
            Vue.cookie = this;
        },
```

LittleWhiteLoti provided this fix, all the credit to them: https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies/issues/59#issuecomment-823796719

Comment: Copied and pasted that line from the original post, saved it, restarted my IDE, and I'm still getting the same error. Also getting a ```[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <Layout install=fn<install> config=fn<config> get=fn<get>  ... > 
  at <Home install=fn<install> config=fn<config> get=fn<get>  ... > 
  at <App install=fn<install> config=fn<config> get=fn<get>  ... >``` error when clicking the cookie button.

Comment: Ran npm uninstall and install for vue-cookies again but, still getting the same error messages.

Comment: If you re-install the package, you're going to get the same issue and might need to rewrite the code fix in the answer. I think the best thing is to change to another module that can work with Vue 3. A quick Google search and maybe this could work for you? https://github.com/anish2690/vue-cookie-next